# Using variable in jQuery Slick slideshow to set initial slide doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, slick.js

I'm using a slideshow on my website using [jQuery Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

My slideshow is hidden when page is loaded, and I have some thumbnails to click on to open my slideshow.
Each thumbnail has a data-number attribute (my variable), and when clicking on a thumbnail, my slideshow opens itself, and the initial slide should be set depending on which thumbnails has been clicked.

Here is my code without the variable. I choose thumb 4 just for the example, and it works fine :

```
$(".thumb").click(function(){
  $(".slider").show();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.slider').slick({
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      centerMode: true,   
      initialSlide : 4,
      infinite: true,
      prevArrow : $('.prev'),
      nextArrow : $('.next')});
    $(".slider").css("opacity", 1);
  }, 2000);
});
```

You can see it working on [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmo50w7n/1118/).

Now, when I try to put a variable in my code for the initialSlide, the initial slide is ok, but when I click on "next", my slideshow disappear or is not working properly...
try for example thumb 7...

Here is my code :

```
$(".thumb").click(function(){
  var initialslide = $(this).attr("data-number");
  $(".slider").show();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.slider').slick({
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      centerMode: true,   
      initialSlide : initialslide,
      infinite: true,
      prevArrow : $('.prev'),
      nextArrow : $('.next')});
    $(".slider").css("opacity", 1);
  }, 200);
});
```

See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmo50w7n/1115/) to see it in action : if you click on *next* after the slideshow appears, you'll see the problem.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, can anybody help me with this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** use `parseInt` with `$(this).attr("data-number")` or `$(this).data("number")`

I just added `parseInt(initialSlide)` and it seems to have fixed your issue.

```
$(".thumb").click(function(){
  var initialslide = $(this).attr("data-number");

  $(".slider").show();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.slider').slick({
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      centerMode: true,   
      initialSlide : parseInt(initialslide),
      infinite: true,
      prevArrow : $('.prev'),
      nextArrow : $('.next')});
    $(".slider").css("opacity", 1);
  }, 200);
});
```

**Edit:** you can use [jQuery Data method](https://api.jquery.com/data/) directly, instead of `$(this).attr(...)`, which seems to cast to int automagically.

```
$(".thumb").click(function(){
  var initialslide = $(this).data("number");

  $(".slider").show();

  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.slider').slick({
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      centerMode: true,   
      initialSlide : initialslide,
      infinite: true,
      prevArrow : $('.prev'),
      nextArrow : $('.next')});
    $(".slider").css("opacity", 1);
  }, 200);
});
```

Comment: there's some funky stuff with the naming of the data-tag when it comes to accessing them from jQuery. If I remember well, hyphens in HTML code are removed and the next word is capitalized (i.e. an HTML attribute of `data-my-fancy-name` becomes `$(this).data("myFancyName")` from jQuery's perspective). It should be in the doc but you may have to go through some trials and errors.